# Treeview binding problem

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have a window MainWindow.xaml and

private static Tutorial tutorial; there.

Also I have class Structure.cs where I describe child types

```
public class Tutorial
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Chapter> Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
}


public class Chapter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Unit> Units = new List<Unit>();
}

public class Unit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Frame> Frames = new List<Frame>();
    ... 

}
```

I want to bind tutorial structure to treeview. How can I do this?

I tried this way.

```
                    <TreeView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="treeViewStruct" Margin="5,0,5,0" Background="LemonChiffon" BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Cursor="Hand">
                        <TreeView.Resources>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type Structure:Chapter}"
                            ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Units}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Structure:Unit}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.Resources>
                    </TreeView>
```

It doesn't work.
Please, help! I'm a newbie in WPF. I need dynamic tree
so that when I add a chapter or a unit in the object tutorial, tree is updated. 
And for this way of binding please throw the idea how can I get a collection item, when I selected some tree node.

Answer (score 0):

This may help :

```
<HierarchicalDateTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:Tutorial}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Chapters}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDateTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDateTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:Chapter}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDateTemplate>

    <DateTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:Unit}"
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DateTemplate>
```